# Google sheets as Datasource in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-sheets-api, ionic3

I am new to **Ionic** platform and I started with **Ionic 3**. I made a sample HTML page design and did all validation part in `.ts` file using `js`. Now my task is to use **google sheets** as `datasource`. I executed the `get()` method function from the sheet. But I didnt know how to post the value to the sheet.

I have a spreadsheet url with a spreadsheet ID with me.

The code I used to get the values from spreadsheet.

```
this.dataId = 'mySpreadSheetID';
      this.gDrive.load(this.dataId)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
         this.persons = data;
         console.log(this.persons[0].employeeid);

        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Can anyone guide me on **how to post data to spreadsheet**.

Comment: Check this URL and go inside `create` && `append` method - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

Comment: @UtkarshDubey Any tutorials available for the same